# how to use javascript or jquery for running functions that are placed in an array

Tags: javascript, jquery, function

I have a JavaScript array that contains 150 JavaScript functions (these functions return financial indicators). when i load my page, i have this array. I'm wondering is it possible to use these loaded functions on that page?

I've converted my array to string and picture below shows how it looks like in alert mode:

[arry alert mode http://bsl.site40.net/pic/8cdf49ea54ee.jpg](http://bsl.site40.net/pic/8cdf49ea54ee.jpg)

In above picture the (faunction a, b, c) are where my functions take place and there is 150 functions (the string {"itemCode":___}, will be repated each time i ad a function). I think there should be some string replace and then inserting the functions on that page in someway. mmm i don't know. can you help me?
I have another question: is it possible for a javascript array to be very long (for example 20000 characters)?

**Edit**: my array has complete code of functions. in that picture i showed only their name in order to picture be viewable

Comment: Does your array contain the "names" of functions, or the actual code that declares the functions?

Comment: Did you replace the actual function with "function a" for illustration? if so and the items are function objects  `r = yourArray[0].ItemCode();` ?

Comment: @gavin my array has full function. in that picture i showed only their name in order to picture be viewable.

Comment: In which case, you could simply use `Eval` as it will first convert your text into a json object and then  you can loop through each of the items and call the function. The only issue may be executing the function separately.

Comment: @Alex K: suppose i have complete code of functions in that array. can you tell me how i can use them in my page please?

Comment: Does array_name[0]['ItemCode'](); call the first function, or is the function in quotes?  If the function code is in quotes, you might need to use eval().Maybe: eval(array_name[0]['ItemCode'])()?

Comment: @Nathan: for example my first array is like this
[{"itemcode":"function Add(){vara=parseInt(document.getElementById("txt1").value);var b=parseInt(document.getElementById("txt2").value);
  document.getElementById("txt3").value=a + b;}",[{"itemcode":... .

Comment: @DavidPeterson: To debug this, I'd recommend using a small debugging array, with one object, like this: var test_array = [{"itemcode": "function() { alert('it worked!'); }"}].  First try alert(test_array[0]).  If that gives you the object, try alert(test_array[0]['itemcode']);. If that gives you the function code, you are almost there.  In order to change the string that looks like a function into an actual function, you use eval: eval(test_array[0]['itemcode'])();

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest you use a json object instead of an array, it will be easier to look up.
If you keep using an array you will have to loop over the array in order to find the correct functionname/function.

If your json object holds function names that are declared globally you can call them like this

```
var functionName = "myFunc";
window[functionName]();
```

But you probably should not declare your functions globally but store them in some sort of namespace.

If your json object contains the actual function ( and i would recommend this ), you can call it with

```
var functionName = "myFunc";
myObject[functionName]();
```

If your object contains the function code as a string, you will have to eval it to execute it. Your function will need to be wrapped in parentheses, i would not suggest this method !
You would be even better off to dynamically load the functions with some sort of jsonp.

```
var functionName = "myFunc";
var myFunc = eval('(' + myObject[functionName] + ')');
myFunc();
```

An array can contain a maximum of 4,294,967,296 elements, but you will have obliterated your performance long before you reach that, i'm not so sure about json objects tough.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the function eval(string) if the functions are stored as strings. This is not recommended though. If they are stored as objects using parenthesis like this (functionName) will be enough.